# i´m trying make a crud, but when a use the insert´s button happen an error

Tags: python

i´m trying make a crud, but when a use the insert´s button happen an error, everytime I try add in crud this happen:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\mclov\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line                           1892, in __call__
        return self.func(*args)
      File "C:\Users\mclov\pythonProject1\fluxo.py", line 53, in insertdata
        inserir(lista)
      File "C:\Users\mclov\pythonProject1\lira.py", line 14, in inserir
        cursor = conexao.cursor()
      File "C:\Users\mclov\abadabado\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection_cext.py", line     706,         in cursor
        raise OperationalError("MySQL Connection not available.")
    mysql.connector.errors.OperationalError: MySQL Connection not available.
```

Code:

```
def insertdata():
    tempo = entry_tempo.get()
    evento = entry_descrição.get()
    debito = entry_entrada.get()
    credito = entry_saida.get()
    lista = [tempo, evento, debito, credito]
    if evento == '' or tempo == '' or credito=='' or debito=='':
        messagebox.showerror("campo não pode ser vazio")
    else:
        inserir(lista)
        messagebox.showinfo("todos os dados foram registrados")
        entry_tempo.delete(0, "end")
        entry_descrição.delete(0, "end")
        entry_entrada.delete(0, "end")
        entry_saida.delete(0, "end")

    for widget in frame_tabela.winfo_children():
        widget.destroy()

    showitself()
```

Comment: You will need to show your `inserir` code.

Comment: @AKX def inserir(i):
    with conexao:
        cursor = conexao.cursor()
        comando = "INSERT INTO caixa (DATA, EVENTO, DÉBITO, CRÉDITO, SALDO) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?);"
        cursor.execute(comando, i)

Answer (score 0):

Seems the main problem there is the MySQL connection, I would suggest:

- Test your MySQL connection from a terminal or any other tool like Workbench
- Check the "inserir" function, and evaluate if data insertion is working from there
- Debug your code from other methods also, maybe: connections, CRUDs functions, and so on

Comment: I´ve tried this second method and it wasn´t work:

Comment: happen this:  File "C:\Users\mclov\abadabado\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor_cext.py", line 325, in execute
    raise ProgrammingError(
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement. what´s that means? I thought it was about the list that I´ve trying put in mysql, then I copied what already was in mysql, but still didn´t work

Comment: the code: lista = [2021-12-12, "ece", 90.00, 90.00, 90.00]
def inserir(i):
    with conexao:
        cursor = conexao.cursor()
        comando = "INSERT INTO caixa (DATA, EVENTO, DÉBITO, CRÉDITO) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?);"
        cursor.execute(comando,i)

inserir(lista)